# Nodejs aws-sdk v2 read AVRO file

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, avro

I'm using aws-sdk v2 precisely `"aws-sdk": "2.1032.0"`. I have avro files in a AWS S3. To read them I use the following:

```
const response = await s3.getObject({
      Bucket: 'bucketname',
      Key: 'key'
    }).promise();

const data = response.Body.toString()
```

The problem is that the data not decoded correctly check this result for example: `Objavro.schema�{"type":"record","name"`. I tried `toString('binary')`, `toString('utf-8')`
but basically we get the same result.

Any idea how to read properly the content of the Avro file from S3?

Thank you

Comment: The Avro file format is not text afaik so I doubt you can convert it to string. I'd expect `response.Body` to be a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) that you can use anywhere a Buffer is viable, e.g as input to some Avro decode function.

Comment: Yep what I need is a decoder function for the pipe

Comment: I'm sure you're familiar with the various options but [avsc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avsc) is MIT-licensed and popular.

Comment: Unfortunately the avroBlobDecoder function provided by the library is not working